# Checkboxlist in Lightswitch HTML client

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm new to Lightswitch so please bear with me if this is a stupid, or obvious question. This question is about the Lightswitch HTML client - not the desktop client.

I have the scenario where I have an article that can be tagged against one or more destinations (countries). Ideally, when adding or editing an article, there are multiple tabs. One for details (title, standfirst, body etc.) and another one for tagging. Normally I'd implement this using a checkboxlist.

Any ideas on how would I implement this scenario in Lightswitch would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hope it helps:

The default control type for a Boolean data type is the FlipSwitch control, but you can easily substitute a CheckBox by using a custom control.

In the screen designer, choose the node for a Boolean field, and change the control type from FlipSwitch to Custom Control.
In the Properties window, in the Height section, choose Min and enter 100.This is necessary because the CheckBox control is taller than a standard TextBox control. If your form uses other control types, you may need to adjust this value.
In the General section, choose the Edit Render Code link.
In the Code Editor, add the following code to the render method:
JavaScript

```
// Create the checkbox and add it to the DOM.
    var checkbox = $("<input type='checkbox'/>")
            .css({
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                margin: "10px"
            })
            .appendTo($(element));

    // Determine if the change was initiated by the user.
    var changingValue = false;

    checkbox.change(function () {
        changingValue = true;
        contentItem.value = checkbox[0].checked;
        changingValue = false;
    });
    contentItem.dataBind("value", function (newValue) {
        if (!changingValue) {
            checkbox[0].checked = newValue;
        }
    });
```

If you’re displaying a CheckBox for a required field on an Add/Edit screen, you’ll also want to set an initial value for the control, otherwise the user may get a validation error.
To set an initial value, in the Entity Designer, on the Perspective bar, choose the HTMLClient tab.
In the Write Code list, choose created.
In the Code Editor, set the initial values by adding code to the created method:
JavaScript
entity.FieldName = new Boolean();
    entity.FieldName = 'true';
Replace FieldName with the name of your Boolean field. To initialize the control to an unchecked state, replace true with false.

Comment: this is the best answer for adding check boxes ive found on the web, good job!!

Comment: I am afraid the final part for setting default values, will not work for the HTML Client project. It only worked for the deprecated Silverlight projects. You have to set defaults in the DB function hooks (e.g. *_inserted) or maybe the javascript create() function hook during the screen-object creation.